# Get messages from server in real-time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It's generally a common question.

I wonder how do mail apps implement functionality of email-receiving?
I need to implement a simple sync between two devices(for example) using my web service.

Imagine a to do list app.

Is it possible to implement such a functionality: device1 makes an entry,then sends a message to webservice, webservice informs device2 that changes took place and device2 adjusts its data and displays that entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are 2 ways:

1. polling, each device asks the webserver for changes every N minutes: new todo, delete a todo, change a todo, ... and then each device will adjust. The frequency of the poll depends of the level of real time you are looking for. It can be 1 call every second or every 12 hours or much more.
2. implement a kind of [BOSH protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html): the device opens a connection to the server. The server keeps it open until there something new to send to the device or the connection times out. In that case, the device reopens it.

Option 1 is better for your todo app because you don't need real-time accuracy. The option 2 is better for a chat application where you don't want to wait for the message.

Comment: I'm using polling in my other app. I'd like to know if are there more elegant ways. Asking web server costs some traffic, the second way worth seeing. Does it covers socket programming?

Comment: You can also imagine a peer-to-peer mechanism between your devices. It mainly depends on your app.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS what you want could easily be implement with push notifications.
As soon as the server detects changes that device2 needs to be aware of the server will send a push notification to that device.

After the user views the notification the app should update it self, it would also be a good idea to let the app update it self when coming to the foreground.

The reason for doing it with Push Notification and not polling is that if your app is in the background you can only continue to run a process for 10 min max. You might get around this by adding the background mode to your app, like VOIP, Audio or location. But if you app does not fall in those categories apple might reject your app.

With Push notification the device will receive the notification even if your app isn't running or in background.